# Can't access to Json file using Jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to access to the Json of this link with Javascript of Jquery, I tried a lot of different codes, but nothing to do. This is the file of I want to access: http://www.subspedia.tv/API/getAllSeries.php

And this is an example of one my test:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Subspedia</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src ='http://www.subspedia.tv/API/getAllSeries.php/path/to/jsonp?callback=foo';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for further help.

Comment: That URL returns JSON not JSONP.

Comment: The URL provided doesn't have the «Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *» in the response.

Comment: Are you sure that url supports JSONP? The callback param is meant to signal the source server to wrap the js in that callback function. You don't write the function. But I see that url is not wrapping it. So, it's probably not supported.

Comment: The response is JSON.

Comment: @Danny, JSONP doesn't require Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Exactly. However, the response is not JSONP.

Comment: Thanks for answers, now that I know that the server doesn't support JSONP I tried to receive the JSON using "getJSON()" of Jquery but it doesn't work